# Are there any methods for detecting binary time series periodicity?

Tags: statistics, time-series, data-science, data-mining, periodicity

I am struggling with finding methods which can be used to detect the periodicity of binary time series.(the binary time series look like 0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1... or 1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0...)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve this problem by using a Python's library, I think. I never experienced it but when I google it as "python how to detect a periodicity" then one of the first links on the search result was [this](https://pypi.org/project/periodicity/).

According to this package;

> Useful tools for analysis of periodicities in time series data.
>
> Documentation: https://periodicity.readthedocs.io
>
> Currently includes:
>
> - Auto-Correlation Function
> - Spectral methods:
>
>   - Lomb-Scargle periodogram
>   - Wavelet Transform
>   - Hilbert-Huang Transform (WIP)
> - Phase-folding methods:
>
>   - String Length
>   - Phase Dispersion Minimization
>   - Analysis of Variance (soon™)
> - Gaussian Processes:
>
>   - `george` implementation
>   - `celerite` implementation
>   - `pymc3` implementation (soon™)

Hope, this helps.